# Getting Double Game Controller Devices When One Plugged In

Tags: 20.04, games, joystick

When I plug in a game controller, Ubuntu returns 2 devices for it. When I plug in my XBox 360 controller, JSTest-gtk shows 2 XBox 360 controllers, but only one of them receives input. When I plug in my Logitech controller, JSTest-gtk shows  Logitech and a 360 controller in the list, but again, only one receives input. If I plug in both controllers, I get a list of 1 logitech and 3 360 controllers. These controllers have separate device paths.

Is there any way to disable the extra non-functioning controller devices?

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

After checking just about everything else, driver and hardware configuration wise, I tried exiting out of Steam. That brought my devices back to the correct number. Under Steam's general Controller Settings, I disabled the different controller configuration support checkboxes and saved. Then unplugged and plugged in my controllers and jstest-gtk showed the correct number of controllers.

So the issue is with Steam, which is something I can deal with.